# Django-haystack - how to represent relations in search indexes?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

So I'm trying to index some items with Django-Haystack (elasticsearch backend), one of the indexing criteria being tags on the item, which are a m2m relation(I implemented my own custom solution as it was easier for me than using taggit), here is what my models look like.

```
class GalleryTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='tag', unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag


class Tag(GalleryTag):
    pass


class Artist(GalleryTag):
    pass


class Character(GalleryTag):
    pass

class Gallery(models.Model):    
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character, blank=True, related_name='characters')
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, blank=True, related_name='artists')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='tags')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The object I'm trying to index to be searchable is Gallery, and I would like to be able to have the tags, artists, and characters(all the m2ms) be one of the searchable criteria on them. I could not really find anything about how to make relations searchable, the basic examples only use completely flat models. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to pull in the data in the template file of `GalleryIndex`.
Something like:

```
{% for s in object.hasTags.all %}
{{t.tag}}
{% endfor %}
```

If, for whatever reason, resolving your relation is too complex for a template then add a field called tags to `GalleryIndex` and add a routine `prepare_tags(self, obj)` that queries the relevant data, concatenates and returns it as a string.